# wp7 advertising - unexpected error during response processing ECN

Tags: windows-phone-7, ads

I am using Microsoft's AdControl in my app that I am developing. I have registered at pubcentral and using the correct ApplicationID and AppUnitID.  Also, setting the AdControl.TestMode = false.  The ads were getting displayed correctly yesterday but today, I get this error - An unexpected error occurred during response processing (Name: ECN).

Has anyone else noticed this issue?

I am using January 2011 tools for WP7.  Not sure if this is an issue with the Emulator.

Comment: I would really like to get an answer on this one, I'm having the same issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Just a quick update. My app with ads that weren't working during development got published this morning and all of the ads are working when I downloaded it straight from the marketplace. Still not completely sure of the reason but I thought that information may be useful.

Ok - I've spent far too much time researching this. Apparently there are a lot of people having this error. I think it may have something to do with the impending update of the WP7 because it's relatively recent. If you check out the official forums (http://community.microsoftadvertising.com/forums/32.aspx) there are tons of posts describing the same issue.

For some reason I am still getting impressions with my AdControl despite the lack of visual advertisement. My suggestion is to leave the code in your app and try and publish it (this is the route I'm going to take at least) and hopefully they will start serving ads again soon.